# Locust/pyCharm: Each end point with N users to achieve X RPS

Tags: python, pycharm, locust

I am working on Locust/pyCharm project to have separate file for each end point with different no of users to achieve different RPS for each endpoint.

In code snippet below if I remove

```
if __name__ == '__main__':  ApiUser().run()
```

and run .py file using command like

locust -f .\locustfiles\test.py --host https://something.another.nothing --users 34 --hatch-rate 10

I see locust working as expected.

Sample code below throws error. What am I missing?

```
from locust import HttpUser, task, between, TaskSet, User
headerJsonContent = {'Content-Type': 'application/json',  'Accept': 'application/json'}
URL2 = "/Auth/report"
host = "https://something.another.nothing"
NoOfUse = 50
class MyBaseTasks(TaskSet):
    @task
    def getData(self):
        self.client.get(URL2 = "/Auth/report", verify=False)
class ApiUser(HttpUser):
    tasks = [MyBaseTasks]
    wait_time = between(0.100, 1.500)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ApiUser().run()
```

***ERROR**: *super(HttpUser, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'environment'**

Comment: Hmm... your question is a little confusing. I answered the second part of your question (why you get the error), but that should only occur if you try to run the file directly (not via locust -f ...) But how does this relate to RPS?

Comment: Using single file, I am able to use Locust. I mentioned RPS to give context for what I am trying to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users need an environment parameter. Try something like this:

```
from locust.env import Environment

if __name__ == '__main__':
    env = Environment()
    ApiUser(env).run()
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped. My new error is "Either in the host attribute in the User class, or on the command line using the --host option.")"

Comment: Set the host attribute inside ApiUser instead of at the global level.

Comment: Hmm I tried something like this class ApiUser(HttpUser):
    host = data.host
    user = data.userCount
    hatch-rate = data.hatchRate
    tasks = [MyUserTasks]
     where data has values of corresponding config. Looks like I am missing something as I can specify host, but not users and hatch-rate

Comment: Only host can be specified in code, user count and hatch rate need to come from configuration (command line, config file or env vars). run locust --help for more info

Comment: Checked help already. and I am not clear what I am missing in using config file.

Comment: https://docs.locust.io/en/latest/configuration.html#configuration-file But just to be clear: the normal way to set user count and hatch rate is using command line parameters (-u / -r)

Comment: Thank you. I am looking for way to setup No of user/hatchRate per end point. Check out my q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63622439/multiple-tasks-and-reading-user-and-hatch-rate-from-locust-config-file/63623430#63623430